# function parameter not in scope in function body?

Tags: haskell

I am working through some exercises to learn me some Haskell (for greater good).

The following is my attempt at a BubbleSort:

```
bubbleSort :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
bubbleSort xs = let 
                  (state, bubbled) = bubble True xs
                in  
                  if not state
                  then bubbleSort bubbled
                  else bubbled
  where
    bubble :: Bool -> [Integer] -> (Bool, [Integer])
    bubble changed [] = (changed, []) 
    bubble changed [x] = (changed, [a])
    bubble changed (a:b:as) | compare a b == GT = (fst bubble False (a:as), b:(snd bubble False (a:as)))
                            | otherwise = (fst bubble (changed && True) (b:as), a:(snd bubble (changed && True) (b:as)))
```

This errors out on the final line (in the otherwise clause) with: `Not in scope: 'a'`

I'm honestly not sure whether I'm just very tired or I'm missing something very fundamental but, as far as I understand, a should be in scope, given that it was passed in as part of the (a:b:as) pattern?
Is that not correct?

Comment: The issue I think was that `fst bubble False (a:as)` needs to be `fst $ bubble False (a:as)` and likewise w/ where `snd` is called.

Comment: This is where the error was: `bubble changed [x] = (changed, [a])`.  *Not* in the `otherwise` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `otherwise` case is fine, but not this case: `bubble changed [x] = (changed, [a])`... `a` is not in scope.

```
import           Data.List       (sort)
import           Test.QuickCheck

main :: IO ()
main = verboseCheck isValidSort >> verboseCheck idempotent

isValidSort, idempotent :: [Integer] -> Bool
isValidSort xs = sort xs == bubbleSort xs
idempotent  xs = bubbleSort (bubbleSort xs) == bubbleSort xs

bubbleSort :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
bubbleSort xs = let (state, bubbled) = bubble True xs
                in if not state
                   then bubbleSort bubbled
                   else bubbled
  where
    bubble :: Bool -> [Integer] -> (Bool, [Integer])
    bubble changed [] = (changed, [])
    bubble changed [x] = (changed, [x])
    bubble changed (a:b:as) | compare a b == GT = (fst $ bubble False (a:as), b:(snd $ bubble False (a:as)))
                            | otherwise = (fst $ bubble (changed && True) (b:as), a:(snd $ bubble (changed && True) (b:as)))
```

Comment: while that works and that is awesome, I honestly can't tell what the difference to my code is and why this works when mine didn't. :/

Comment: @AbrahamP. You had a small issue when calling the `fst` function. `fst  bubble False (a:as)` was attemping to apply `fst` to `bubble`, which is a type error, you first needed to evaluate the right hand side of your equation using `($)`. So doing `fst $ bubble False (a:as)` accomplishes that.

Comment: `a` is not in scope since it's defined in a different case. Your `otherwise`case is fine, but not this case: `bubble changed [x] = (changed, [a])`